# What's wrong with this C++ code? (undeclared identifier)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Getting this error: `(68): error C2065: 'programend' : undeclared identifier`

(Off-topic note: I know that using using namespace std is bad practice, but I didn't feel like typing std:: in front of everything.  I will if that's what's causing the error, however.)

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    do{
    system("title Mini-Calc");
    cout << "Hello World!  Welcome to Dustin's C++ Calculator!" << endl;
    cout << "To get started, enter a number:" << endl;

    int operation;
    double num1, num2, answer;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Now enter another number:" << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "Please type the corrresponding number for the operation desired, and press enter." << endl;
    cout << "1 = +, 2 = -, 3 = x, 4 = /" << endl;

    cin >> operation;

    switch(operation) {
        case 1:
            answer=num1+num2;
        break;

        case 2:
            answer=num1-num2;
        break;

        case 3:
            answer=num1*num2;
        break;

        case 4:
            answer=num1/num2;
        break;

    }

    cout << "The answer is: " << endl;
    cout << answer << endl;

    bool programend;

    cout << "Would you like to end the program? (y for yes, n for no)" << endl;

    cin >> programend;

    switch(programend) {
        case 'y':
            programend=true;
        break;

        case 'n':
            programend=false;
        break;

        case 'Y':
            programend=true;
        break;

        case 'N':
            programend=false;
        break;
        }
    } while (programend==false);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you'd intent that properly, you'd notice that `programend` is declared inside the `do` loop, but it is referenced outside of it, after its closing `}`.

Comment: Also, you declared programend as a bool, but I think you wanted a char.

Comment: Also, `bool` data type implies `true` or `false`, while you are using incorrect case labels.

Comment: A bool can contain the values `true` and `false`. It does not contain the **character** `Y`, or the **character** `N`. "Just switching" y and n won't change that.

Comment: Really?  So you can't switch y and n to true and false?  My mistake.  

Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you take out the do...while contents, you’ll see that `programend` is not declared in the right scope:

```
int main(void) {
    do{
        ...
    } while (programend==false);
    return 0;
}
```

It should be declared between the `main` and the `do` to be available.

Answer (score 0):

you declare `programend` as boolean value but checking like as character

```
 bool programend;
```

change it to

```
 char programend;
```

or use two different variable for this purpose like following

```
bool programend;
char choice;

cout << "Would you like to end the program? (y for yes, n for no)" << endl;

cin >> choice;

switch(choice) {
    case 'y':
        programend=true;
    break;
```

Comment: That's why I have the switch statement. To take the y or n and make it a true or false.

Comment: also declare `bool programend` before the loop

Comment: you taking `y` or `n` in the 'programend' variable which is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

your declaration of programend is inside the do inner block, but you test it in the termination: you can move outside, for example at top. And initialize it:

```
int main(void) {
  bool programend = false;
  do {
  } while (...)
}
```

And declare a variable for reading cin:

```
 int ch;
 cin >> ch;
 switch (ch) {
  ...
 }
```